# powershell: get last block (pattern) and below of txt file

Tags: powershell

I am new in powershell.

I want to grep the last "block" of a log file to a variable.

logfile:

```
aaaa
bbbb
______________________________________
cccc
dddd
______________________________________
eeee
ffff
```

Now I want to get all text below the last existing seperator "______________________________________".
So, output should be in this example:

```
eeee
ffff
```

In linux bash it would be (this is running fine):

```
LAST_RUN=`echo "${logfile##*______________________________________}"`
```

I tried a lot of things. This is working but I think not that "elegant":

```
Get-Content $logfile | Select-String "______________________________________" -Context 0,50000| Select-Object -last 1
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could shorten your regex pattern by using a quantifier or use a more sophisticated regex but if it's working .... does it have to be "elegant"?  ;-) ... and BTW: You can provide a file directly to `Select-String` by using it's parameter `-Path`

Comment: Would this be more "elegant"? `((Get-Content -Path 'D:\TheInputFile.log' -Raw) -split '_{2,}')[-1]`